# RMQClient(RabbitMQ) get Handshake timed out error

Tags: ios, xcode, rabbitmq, mqtt

I use `pod RMQClient` and `pod install` to install *RMQClient* in my project. Then I `import <RMQClient/RMQClient.h>` in *ViewController*.
According to the official guidance, I write some code, but when I run this project, I get **Handshake timed out** error.

Full Error:

```
2017-10-17 11:32:06.960214+0800 RMQDemo[1637:557786] Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x6080000ff780> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=8 "Error creating CFStreams" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error creating CFStreams}
2017-10-17 11:32:06.963773+0800 RMQDemo[1637:557786] Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x6000002e1500> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9847 "(null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error code definition can be found in Apple's SecureTransport.h}
2017-10-17 11:32:16.956467+0800 RMQDemo[1637:557769] Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x6080000ff780> failedToConnectWithError: Error Domain=com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-objc-client Code=1 "Handshake timed out." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Handshake timed out.}
2017-10-17 11:32:16.959851+0800 RMQDemo[1637:557769] Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x6000002e1500> failedToConnectWithError: Error Domain=com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-objc-client Code=1 "Handshake timed out." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Handshake timed out.}
```

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self send];
    [self receive];
}
- (void)send
{
    RMQConnection * conn = [[RMQConnection alloc] initWithUri:@"amqps://username:password@192.168.x.x:5672" delegate:[RMQConnectionDelegateLogger new]];
    [conn start];
    id<RMQChannel>channel = [conn createChannel];
    RMQQueue * queue = [channel queue:@"hello"];
    [channel.defaultExchange publish:[@"hello world" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] routingKey:queue.name];
    [conn close];
}
- (void)receive
{
    RMQConnection * conn = [[RMQConnection alloc] initWithUri:@"amqps://username:password@192.168.x.x:5672" delegate:[RMQConnectionDelegateLogger new]];
    [conn start];
    id<RMQChannel>channel = [conn createChannel];
    RMQQueue * queue = [channel queue:@"hello"];
    [queue subscribe:^(RMQMessage * _Nonnull message) {
        NSLog(@"message:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:message.body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }];
    [conn close];
}
```

How to solve this problem? How to use this framework?

Platform:Xcode 9, iPhone8 simulator, iOS11

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, it is same to the demo code on the website.

From the error info, it says something is wrong while creating CFStreams.  According to the error code -9847, maybe the service is not working now, please check the service status first !

> This tutorial assumes RabbitMQ is installed and running on localhost
>   on standard port (5672). In case you use a different host, port or
>   credentials, connections settings would require adjusting.

Comment: The service is running.